# How to setup and run programs on a newly installed SSD (already have a hard drive)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

So I recently bought and installed a new SSD. I already have an existing hard drive.

(EDIT: I thought I could see my SSD under 'computer management', but it was actually just my recovery partition.)

I go to Settings => Storage => View Storage on other drives, and it's not listed.

I also go to the file explorer and it's not listed (I can only see the C drive).

Do I need to go into BIOS mode and do something? Also, do I need to install Windows OS on my new SSD?

TL; DR how do I setup and run programs on my new SSD (when I already am running on an HDD).

Specs

```
Windows 10
EVO 86 SSD
HDD 1 TB 
Cyberpower pc
```

Comment: Are you asking how to clone your drive, to replace the hdd with the sdd?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as admin in a terminal:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk n
clean
```

I would go back to Computer Mangement, but you can continue in diskpart:

```
create part pri
assign letter=z
```

More on diskpart: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer that worked for me.

1. Check the SSD sata power cable is plugged into your ssd from your power supply (I only had the sata 3 cable plugged up, I didn't realize I needed a separate cable for the power).
2. If your original HDD is still running your computer and you want to run your SSD instead, restart your computer in BIOS mode and make sure the boot order has your SSD being launched first.
3. Install windows on your SSD (have a windows install disk or flash drive with windows on it ready).
4. Relaunch and you should be good to go (I was able to see both my HDD and SSD in my file explorer at this point, and started migrating some of my applications to my SSD) (Alternatively, you can use data migration software).